# Converting LinearGradientBrush to Color

Tags: c#, windows, xaml

I am creating an application that takes advantage of Bing Maps in Windows 8, C# and XAML. I currently have created a MapPolygon and I would like the fill color to be a LinearGradientBrush or any kind of Gradient color. Any ideas of how to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance, 
Jake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe what you're trying to do is possible. The property is [FillColor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh846506.aspx) and it is of type [Color](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.color.aspx). Color can't be a Gradient the way a Brush could be. It has to be a color.

Comment: That makes sense. Any other suggestions on how to accomplish this?

Comment: Not off the top of my head. I don't have much experience with the Bing Maps stuff yet. Doesn't seem possible at all with MapPolygon. Don't know if there are any alternatives to using MapPolygon.